# How to enable/disable Hermes based on Android/iOS Environment Variables in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, environment-variables

Due to compatibility issues of Hermes (in RN +71.0) with [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger), I want to disable Hermes on Development and enable it on Production automatically, with Android/iOS specific ENV files.

In `gradle.properties`:

```
# Use this property to enable or disable the Hermes JS engine.
# If set to false, you will be using JSC instead.
hermesEnabled=true
```

In `Podfile`:

```
  use_react_native!(
    .....

    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,

    .....
  )
```

I'm not quite familiar with setting up Android/iOS environment variables, so I was wondering how I can use it to enable/disable Hermes based on my environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable.

For example, if you are using Expo you can handle it with the `CI=1`:

```
:hermes_enabled => ENV['CI'] == '1',
```

A non-Expo solution can be to create a `.json` file with properties for `Podfile`, f.e. `podfile-config.js`. In this `.js` you can set different flag, like:

```
{
  "enableHermes": "true",
  "enableFlipper": "false"
  ...
}
```

The all that you need to do in the `Podfile` is to access the variables:

```
require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'podfile-config.js'))) rescue {}
```

and to access them:

```
:hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['enableHermes'] == "true"
```

And at the end, you probably know that will need to call `pod install` :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm using React Native CLI.

Comment: @Nima I've just updated the post :)

Comment: Many thanks and I'll be sure to test it out. Would the Android implementation be the same as well?