# React native expo java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using expo for my application. Everything works on the emulator, on a real User device java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so. I can't understand why this is happening. I can't do anything for the second day

I added "hermesEnabled" to the app.json and nothing has changed. Delete main in app.json

Comment: please use this as reference and disable hermes and then try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976189/how-to-enable-disable-hermes-based-on-android-ios-environment-variables-in-react

Comment: I already did this, it doesn't work

Comment: Please let us know if you managed to find a solution for this.